# permotation group S13 question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

if a = (1 2 4 8) (3 5 7 9 11 13) (6 12) ∈ S13, and b= (1 2 3 4 5 6) (7 8 9 10) (11 12) ∈ S13 ,let σ ∈ S13 a = σbσ−1 then how much σ like this are there in S13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Prove that if $\;(i_1\;i_2\;\ldots\;i_k)\;$ is a cycle in $\;S_n\;$ and we take *any* element $\;\sigma\in S_n\;$ , then

$$\sigma(i_1\;i_2\;\ldots\;i_k)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\;\sigma(i_2)\;\ldots\;\sigma(i_k))$$

Further hint: if $\;c_1,..,c_r\;$ are cycles (or, in fact, general permutations), then

$$\sigma(c_1\cdot\ldots\cdot c_k)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma c_1\sigma^{-1})(\sigma c_2\sigma^{-1})\cdot\ldots\cdot(\sigma c_r\sigma c_r^{-1})$$

Comment: ok I know that, how does it help me?

Comment: @AmeerAamar This is where the thinking begins...You want $\;a=\sigma b\sigma^{-1}\;$ and you have both $\;a,b\;$...

Comment: ok I can find one σ like that.. so is it just that one or there are more?

Comment: Check carefully. If for example it were only $$(1\;2\;4\;8)=\sigma(7\;8\;9\;10)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(7)\sigma(8)\sigma(9)\sigma(10))$$ then you'd need a permutation s.t. $$\sigma(7)=1,\,\sigma(8)=2,\,\sigma(9)=4,\,\sigma(1)=8$$ . But you could **also** put $\;(1248)=(2481)\;$ , so we **also have** $\;\sigma(7)=2,\,\sigma(8)=4,\,\sigma(9)=8,\,\sigma(10)=1\;$ and etc.

Comment: so its 2*2*2*3!=48 thank you!